# On click, display (slide) details for portfolio use

Tags: jquery, css, html, sliding

This is my html/css: http://jsfiddle.net/StillD/bDMxs/

The pink boxes are my portfolio items. Beneath them I want to present detailed information (whole browser width) of the portfolio item you click. So when you click portfolio item 1, the div's with my footer beneath my whole portfolio should slide down to make room for the details of portfolio item 1. Those details for this portfolio item should appear here. When you click item 2, the details for item 1 should disappear and the details for item 2 should appear.

This is a website which is using this effect (scroll down to the portfolio and click an item):

http://www.applove.se

I mailed the people behind this site and they gave me this:

```
onclick="$('#name').slideDown();
$('#name2').slideUp(); 
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#name.offset().top }, 600);"
```

But I am not able to get it to work. I hope you guys can help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working demo here http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/NHskg/3/

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".portfolio").click(function () {
        $('.description').slideUp(); 
        $('#'+$(this).attr('target')).slideDown();        
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#targetWrapper').offset().top }, 600);
    });
    $(".close").click(function () {
        $('.description').slideUp();        
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#p_img').offset().top }, 600);
    });
});
```

Comment: Woho! I just asked for an example, and you provided it almost instantly. Very much thanks!

Comment: Yep, I'm going to implement this. If it all works i'll accept your answer

Comment: It's kinda working. But, what I need to know is how to force the content beneath the portfolio to slide down to. Because now the description disappears behind the content beneath my portfolio.

EDIT: some parts of the content beneath my portfolio does slide down. But some parts aren't. Is this a css something?

Comment: try to use a new div for all of your descriptions' divs, and use css, float:left; width:100%; for this description div. Coz I cannot see your html markup and css, so I cannot tell exactly. May be you create a jsfiddle.

Comment: When I try making my html/css a fiddle the code doesn't slide any content down beneath the portfolio. So, this is what I have: 

beneath the portfolio is a div containing a new section of my site. It's an 'about me' part. This div has a background color. The content of the div does slide down (text, img, etc). But the div doesn't. So the content of the 'about me' part does slide down, but the coloured background doesn't. I think it's the only part not sliding down.

Comment: I think I fixed the problem!!! Added overflow: hidden to the div below the portfolio!

Comment: Ok, one more question and then it's working perfect. When you click a item it slides perfectly. The close button works awesome. When you have opened one description and you click the previous portfolio item, it works perfect. But when you are watching the description of an item and you click on the next item the whole page scrolls down like an idiot!! It only does this when you click on the next item in the portfolio... In your fiddle it does the same (only less then in my site).

Answer (score 0):

what the example site is doing is basically using anchors (but with a jquery twist).
I would suggest starting from the tabs (in jquery UI) and add whatever sliding effects you want.
reference: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#default

Comment: Yeah, well, I am not that good with jquery yet... (A) I was hoping someone good edit my fiddle a bit with some jquery so I see and understand how to work.. I hope someone will find the time to make me an example!